# How to refetch deeply nested object with React custom hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch

Have hook called *useCategoryTree*. It fetches categories (deeply nested object) from database on componentDidMount. It works well.

Hook also returns function to refetch the categories. However, when refetch function is called the *treeHookState* stays the same and is not updated.

According to React documentation, state updated is done via shallow comparison. Therefore, tried to clone the object with loadash method *_.cloneDeep*, but no luck either.

Would appreciate any help on this topic. Thanks!

**useCategoryTree.ts**

```
import { Nav, INavLink } from '@fluentui/react';

export const useCategoryTree = () => {
  const [treeHookState, setTreeState] = useState<INavLink[]>([]);

  const getCategoriesTree = async () => {
    let response = await fetch('/api/cateogries');
    let data = await response.json();
    return data as INavLink[];
  };
  const refetchTree = () => {
    getCategoriesTree().then((result) => {
      setTreeState(result);
    });
  };

  // fetch categories
  useEffect(() => {
    //loading
    setTreeState((draft: any) => (draft = [{ key: 'loading', name: 'loading', url: '' }]));
    refetchTree();
  }, []);

  return {
    treeHookState,
    refetch: refetchTree
  };
};
```

**CategoryTree.tsx**

```
import { Nav, INavLink } from '@fluentui/react';

export const CategoriesTree: React.FunctionComponent<ICategoriesTreeProps> = () => {
  const { treeHookState: treeState } = useCategoryTree();

  return (
    <>
      <Nav
        groups={[{ links: treeState }]}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

**CreateEditCategory.tsx**

```
const CreateEditCategory: React.FunctionComponent<IProps> = () => {
   // Some code here

   const { refetch: refetchTree } = useCategoryTree();
   const { createCategoryFunction, updateCategoryFunction } = useCategoryMutations(onCompleted);

   function onCompleted() {
      dismissPanel();
      refetchTree();
   }
   // Some more code here
}
```

**useCategoryMutations.ts**

```
import { useMutation } from '@apollo/react-hooks';

export const useCategoryMutations = (propsOnComplete?: () => void) => {
    const [createCategory] = useMutation<CreateCategory, CreateCategoryVariables>(CREATE_CATEGORY, {
    onCompleted() {
      handleCompleted();
    })
    const [updateCategory] = useMutation<UpdateCategory, UpdateCategoryVariables>(UPDATE_CATEGORY, {
    onCompleted() {
      handleCompleted();
    })

   const handleCompleted = () => {
    if (propsOnComplete) propsOnComplete();
   };

    const createCategoryFunction = (
     //...variables
    ) => {
    let createdCategoryId = createCategory({
      variables: {
        // ...variables
      }
    });
      return createdCategoryId;
    };

   // Similar function for edit category
}
```

**Nested object example**

```
const navLinkGroups: INavLinkGroup[] = [
  {
    links: [
      {
        name: 'Home',
        url: 'http://example.com',
        expandAriaLabel: 'Expand Home section',
        collapseAriaLabel: 'Collapse Home section',
        links: [
          {
            name: 'MSN',
            url: 'http://msn.com',
            disabled: true,
            key: 'key2',
            target: '_blank',
            links: [
              {
                name: 'MSNChild',
                url: 'http://msn.com',
                disabled: true,
                key: 'key2',
                target: '_blank'
              },
              {
                name: 'MSNChild',
                url: 'http://msn.com',
                disabled: true,
                key: 'key2',
                target: '_blank'
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        isExpanded: true
      },
      {
        name: 'News',
        url: 'http://cnn.com',
        icon: 'News',
        key: 'key7',
        target: '_blank'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: Avoid deep nested objects in state, especially if they have nested array whose length is unknown. It might work fine now, but down the line it can cause performance problems. Redux or React. In fact, Redux docs touches on this issue and suggests that we architect our state like we would a relational database, which is keeping data as flat as possible.

Comment: what's inside this "useCategoryMutations(refetchTree())" ?

Comment: @VoQuocThang There are GraphQL mutations. 
Updated the question to include the useCategoryMutations as well as it's params -> useCategoryMutations(onCompleted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. It was related to how custom hooks were used, not the deeply nested object.

**Solution:**
Move execution of useCategoryTree hook at the very top level and pass down props to children, according to below documentation. *Refetch* then will update the same state as *treeState*.

> **Do two components using the same Hook share state?** No. Custom Hooks
> are a mechanism to reuse stateful logic (such as setting up a
> subscription and remembering the current value), but every time you
> use a custom Hook, all state and effects inside of it are fully
> isolated.
>
> https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

**App.tsx**

```
const App: React.FunctionComponent<IProps> = () => {
    const { treeHookState: treeState, refetch: refetchTree } = useCategoryTree()

    return (
      <>
         <CategoryTree
            treeState={treeState}
          />
         <CreatedEditCategory
            refetchTree={refetchTree}
         />
      </>
    )
}
```

**CategoryTree.tsx**

```
import { Nav, INavLink } from '@fluentui/react';

export const CategoriesTree: React.FunctionComponent<ICategoriesTreeProps> = ({treeState}) => {

  return (
    <>
      <Nav
        groups={[{ links: treeState }]}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

**CreateEditCategory.tsx**

```
const CreateEditCategory: React.FunctionComponent<IProps> = ({refetchTree}) => {
   // Some code here

   const { createCategoryFunction, updateCategoryFunction } = useCategoryMutations(onCompleted);

   function onCompleted() {
      dismissPanel();
      refetchTree();
   }
   // Some more code here
}
```